# How can I change mapView mapType from within a partial curl?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, android-mapview, uisegmentedcontrol, page-curl

I'm trying to recreate the feature of Google Maps that changes the map type to hybrid or satellite or standard. I have setup a view that's displayed in a partial curl transition. Within this view, is a UISegmentedControl. When it's value is changed, the following code is executed:

```
- (IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self curlViewControllerDidFinish:nil];
        [mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        break;

    case 1:
        [self curlViewControllerDidFinish:nil];
        [mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
        break;

    case 2:
        [self curlViewControllerDidFinish:nil];
        [mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
        break;

    }
}
```

The curl transition does finish, but the mapType does not change. I have tried putting the `[mapview setmapType...` above the `[self curlViewControllerDidFinish...`.

Note: `[mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];` does change the mapType with 1 line of code if executed outside of the curl transition.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS Maps.app most likely uses a delegate to inform the map view that the modal view has selected a new option. Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self curlViewControllerDidFinish:nil];
        [self.delegate setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        break;

    case 1:
        [self curlViewControllerDidFinish:nil];
        [self.delegate setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        break;

    case 2:
        [self curlViewControllerDidFinish:nil];
        [self.delegate setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Still having trouble with it, I'll let you know how I did it once I get it working.